# Swagger Java ApiResponse Map

Tags: java, swagger, springfox

I am trying to get the response example value in the Swagger UI docs to correctly display a map. This is what my map looks like: `Map<Long, List<UserRole>>`. The UserRole object just has two fields, roleId & roleName.

According to the Javadoc for Swagger annotations the responseContainer supports `Valid values are "List", "Set" or "Map". Any other value will be ignored.`

However, this is the implementation inside of the SpringFox Swagger common library:

```java
  if ("List".compareToIgnoreCase(responseContainer) == 0) {
    return Optional.of(resolver.resolve(List.class, response));
  } else if ("Set".compareToIgnoreCase(responseContainer) == 0) {
    return Optional.of(resolver.resolve(Set.class, response));
  } else {
    return Optional.of(resolver.resolve(response));
  }
```

Obviously this does not support a Map.

If I don't specify a response type: `@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK")` then the Swagger docs look like this:

```
{
  "additionalProp1": [
    {
      "roleId": 1234,
      "roleName": "User"
    }
  ],
  "additionalProp2": [
    {
      "roleId": 1234,
      "roleName": "User"
    }
  ],
  "additionalProp3": [
    {
      "roleId": 1234,
      "roleName": "User"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is almost correct except that I need to replace the `additionalPropX` field with a long value. I have tried setting the examples several different ways: `@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK", examples = @Example(value = @ExampleProperty(value = "Puppy"))),`. I don't think that is implemented in SpringFox. I tried creating a new POJO to wrap my response but that just causes some really weird response examples.

I am using the latest Swagger dependencies through Gradle:

```
compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'
compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
```

Is this possible?